# How can I generate a cumulative plot where I can view the number of files by the last modified date?

Tags: date, file-management

I have a large (millions) number of files in a folder, its subfolders and its subsubfolders that were modified over the past 15 years. I'd like to generate a cumulative plot where I can view the number of files by the last modified date, e.g:

[image]

How can I generate a cumulative plot where I can view the number of files by the last modified date?

If that matters, I use Ubuntu.

Comment: You can obtain a count of files by year-month with: `find myDir -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm\n' | sort | uniq -c`, which for 15 years will give 180 rows like`    116 2023-05`. Selecting a start/time range, and accumulating 2 or 3 months together, would be simple awk. For the graphical output, look at `gnuplot`, or settle for some ascii text-based graphing that can do auto-scaling, axes etc.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like:

```
find . -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm\n' | sort | uniq -c | gnuplot -p -e '
  set xdata time;
  set timefmt "%Y-%m";
  set format x "%Y-%m";
  set xtics rotate by 30 right;
  set xlabel "Last modified date";
  plot "-" using 2:1 with lines title "count"'
```

See also `mlr -p bar -f 1` in place of gnuplot for some textual bar chart.

Answer (score 1):

If you like mixing bash / python, you can do it with matplotlib/pandas/seaborn, I really like to use scatter plots for time series:

`pip install --user seaborn matplotlib pandas`

the command as a one-liner:

```
sudo find / -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td\n" | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | python -c 'import sys; import seaborn as sns; import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; import pandas as pd; from datetime import datetime; sns.scatterplot(data=pd.DataFrame([{"y": int(index.strip().split(" ").pop(0)), "x": datetime.strptime(index.strip().split(" ").pop(1), "%Y-%m-%d")} for index in sys.stdin.readlines() if int(index.strip().split(" ").pop(0)) > 1]), x="x", y="y") ; plt.xticks(rotation=90) ; plt.show()'
```

this is useful sometimes in a pinch, but even on this computer it takes a very long time unless you add `-maxdepth 3` after `find /` this distribution also skips dates with fewer than 1 file changed with `int(index.strip().split(" ").pop(0)) > 1`.

You can potentially minimize the amount of time with something like GNU parallel:

`apt install parallel`

`find / -type d -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 | parallel -j8 find {} -type f -printf '"%TY-%Tm-%Td\\n"' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n`

```
sudo find / -type d -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 | parallel -j8 find {} -type f -printf '"%TY-%Tm-%Td\\n"' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | python -c 'import sys; import seaborn as sns; import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; import pandas as pd; from datetime import datetime; sns.scatterplot(data=pd.DataFrame([{"y": int(index.strip().split(" ").pop(0)), "x": datetime.strptime(index.strip().split(" ").pop(1), "%Y-%m-%d")} for index in sys.stdin.readlines() if int(index.strip().split(" ").pop(0)) > 1]), x="x", y="y") ; plt.xticks(rotation=90) ; plt.show()'
```

Also I want to note that in the matplotlib viewer you can zoom in on the dataset to narrow down to a specific date range:

very high level view:

[image]

- this took ~2 minutes to run

Essentially you can turn anything into a one-liner with python but whether you should or not is really up to you. If you want to define python functions that you want to use once for a bash script you'll have to use heredoc. Here's  a list of other things including some info about heredoc that you might be interested in:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374640/how-do-i-calculate-percentiles-with-python-numpy

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30702519/python-c-vs-python-heredoc

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38436215/can-i-save-ipython-command-line-history-to-a-notebook-file

Comment: FYI, `%TY-%Tm-%Td` can be written `%TF`

Comment: Thanks Stéphane, I meant to mention it would be worthwhile to refer to the man page in find because I'm not 100% familiar with all of the formatters myself.

Comment: [Interesting article](https://torbiak.com/post/histogram_gnuplot_vs_matplotlib/) (very relevant to this Q&A) about  gnuplot vs matplotlib to plot *Histograms of timestamped data*.